# Filling columns in Excel

Tags: excel, autofill

I am working on a data entry program and need to have a certain column which is 0,1,2...x with 217 1's, 217 2's etc. I have tried autofilling but I get some weird errors with trend recognition. I.e. I have tried to just put 217 0's, 1's and then click and drag but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any thoughts and / or solutions?

Thanks!

EDIT: SOLUTION

So I was able to create a grid with columns INDEX, VALUE, and REPEATSIZE, where VALUE contains the list of items I wanted repeated. Then I used the index column to generate the position that each item of value should begin at and finally used repeatsize to indicate the number of repeats.

The final column containing all the instances of VALUE has this formula:
CONTENT = =VLOOKUP(ROW()-2,INDEX:VALUE,2)

Hope this helps someone. Thank you all for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following into any cell.

```
=INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/217)
```

Fill down as necessary. That will produce 217 zeroes, then 217 ones, then 217 twos, etc. If you need to start at 217 sequenced ones then drop a `+1` off the right end.

For 217 *a, a, a, a, a, a, ....* then 217 *b, b, b, b, b, ...* adjust to return the ASCII character by ASCII character code.

```
=CHAR(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/217)+97)
```

The [CHAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-BBD249C8-B36E-4A91-8017-1C133F9B837A) returns the character from the numeric code. An **a** is 97.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I wanted to work from a selection, say a,b,c,d...x and have there be 217 a, then b, etc. Any thoughts on how best to modify this?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry - I should've been more clear. I'm thinking more along the lines of a set of terms like "Banana","Horse","Donkey","Gerbil"...."X" and I'd like to autofill 217 of each into a column, where the list is stored in another column in the same sheet.

Comment: You have two examples of the numerical sequencing above. Apply one of them to the *row_num* or *column_num* parameter of an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column is A, in `A218`, put:

```
=A1+1
```

That formula can be used to autofill indefinitely. Job done :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how this would work.

Comment: The forumula is recursive; it will reference 217 cells up. But it reqires you to fill in the first set; other answer is more elegant.
If `A1 to `A217` is 0:
`A218=A1+1=0+1 = 1`
`A219=A2+1=0+1 =1`
`A220=A3+1=0+1=1` etc.
`A435=A218+1=1+1=2` etc

Comment: Ah... I see. That is actually quite elegant as well. Thanks!